# Title position in qgis2web

Tags: leaflet, html, qgis2web, css, web-gis

I try to change the position of the title created by qgis2web to the top left above the zoom control. Right now it is always displayed on the top right side.

And is it somehow possible to make these changes just in the qgis2web template file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the exported `index.html` file in a text editor. Find the line:

```
var title = new L.Control();
```

Change it to:

```
var title = new L.Control({position: 'topleft'});
```

Note that this will be affected by the default position of the zoom controls. To move the title *above* the zoom controls, first find the following code:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    zoomControl:true, maxZoom:
```

Remove `zoomControl: true,`:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    maxZoom:
```

Next, find this code:

```
title.addTo(map);
```

Add to it as follows:

```
title.addTo(map);
L.control.zoom().addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is it possible to display the title above the zoom control just by editing the qgis2web template?

Comment: Not just by editing the template, no. I'll edit my answer to describe how to get the title above the zoom controls.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I edited my question to fit the answer.