# Embed title to qgis2web map

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis2web

Is it possible to show a title "ProjectName" within the map generated by qgis2web? I can put a title in above the map described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383521/adding-logo-and-title-to-an-html-webmap-created-by-qgis2web) and tried to follow the answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283709/title-position-in-qgis2web) to put it above the zoom buttons. But i cant find the lines of code mentioned in the answer such as `var title = new L.Control();`

Using QGIS 3.16

[image]

Edit. I want to do this using openlayers but want the same effect when exporting with leaflet.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot provide the map title in Openlayers in the same way as in Leaflet. However, you are not lost. You have effectively two ways to do it.
The first option is to open your index.html file, where you can modify your code by adding a simple text, just above the `<div>` with your map embedding.

```
     <body>
    <center><h1> Map title </h1></center>
    <div id="map">
```

and in turn, you will have the title above your embedded map

[image]

but if you don't want to mess around with HTML code and you desire the map title inside the map script, the reasonable solution is an edit of **attribution**, at the very end of your `qgis2web.js` file, where:

```
   var qgisAttribution = document.createElement('li');
   qgisAttribution.innerHTML = '<b>Area 5</b>';
```

instead of the link to QGIS, for instance, you can put your own text, and moreover, emphasize it by changing the font properties...

[image]

A more detailed explanation of how to do it, you can find here:

http://www.mkrgeo-blog.com/qgis2web-legend-scale-and-other-elements-in-openlayers-map-library/